# Server compromised - How do I find out what is sending mail

Tags: postfix

A friend of mine has a few small businesses and hosts Wordpress-based sites for them on a dedicated host. The Wordpress installs were neglected for awhile and the host ended up getting compromised. There's now 100's of spam messages going out every second. What can I look at to determine what's generating the mail?

The only way I can get the spam to stop is to shutdown Postfix. We've had it off for a few days to prevent spamming, but this also means he can't send mail from his businesses addresses.

If I shutdown both apache and postfix, netstat shows no remote connections except my SSH login. If I then start postfix (but leave apache stopped), 100's of remote connections to port 25 immediately open. This leads me to believe that some process on the host is doing this, rather than something coming in through Wordpress/some rogue script that we missed in the clean-up. There were also IRC bots on here, but we've removed those, and netstat no longer shows any open connections to IRC.

When I look at ps axjf - all of the smtp processes roll up to /usr/libexec/postfix/master, which has a parent id of 1. This doesn't really give me an idea of where the mail is being generated.

Neither ps nor top show any suspicious processes (as far as I can tell).

What else can I look at to see what's creating/sending the mail? I can post the output of ps whatever_flags_you_want both with and without postfix running, if it will help.

Thanks.

Comment: Wanted to add that I've verified the host is not an open relay using http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx. I see no incoming connections on 25, only outgoing.

Comment: I checked under /var/spool/postfix/active and see a ton of spammy outgoing mail queued up. All these were created by postfix. The from address on each message uses the same domain, so I'm going to check the files under that domain's directory again.

Comment: So obviously Postfix is running, but what's invoking it? You could parse the process list with ps -ef, or ps auxwwf for a nice tree output.  Also use lsof to list all open files.  You may be able to kill the process running now but how would you locate all traces of it? It's very difficult.   You could try a rootkit scanner.  Search for rkhung

Comment: I mean... Search for rkhunter.  You should plan on copying your content out and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses everyone. We did install and run rkhunter, it didn't find anything.

It looks like we actually did take care of this in the initial clean-up, but postfix was trying to resend messages that had been bounced after the host was blacklisted.

There were 100's of thousands of messages stuck in /var/spool/postfix/deferred. I think when I started postfix, it was moving those back to ./active and trying to resend. I just deleted everything in ./deferred and ./active, then started postfix. It doesn't appear that any new messages are being created or sent. I'm thinking this was just me not understanding how postfix works.

I've been running

watch -d -n 1 'ls -lhart /var/spool/postfix/active'

and

watch 'netstat --program --numeric-hosts --numeric-ports --extend | grep -E ":25|postfix|smtp"'

For about 30 minutes and see no outgoing activity.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wipe out the OS entirely and reinstall. So many things could have been altered.

Comment: While that's true, it's helpful to know what permitted the intrusion and what configuration has been modified, to avoid restoring vulnerable programs or trojaned configuration files.